# Merge 2 dataframes based on a condition on column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 :

```
symbol     s_1  .    .     Other columns 
aa          111 .    .       .
ab          21  .    .       .
```

and another dataframe df2 :

```
symbol  .   .    .   Other columns 
aa
aa
aa
ab
ab
ab
ab
ac
```

I want to merge s_1 column to the df2 in such a way that each symbol represents the s_1 value

**I dont want other columns from df1 and want to fill NA to `s_1` when symbol's not available in df1**

The output looks like :

The output looks like :

```
symbol  .   .    .   Other columns  s_1
aa      .   .    .       .          111
aa      .   .    .       .          111
ab      .   .    .       .          21
ab      .   .    .       .          21
ab      .   .    .       .          21
ab      .   .    .       .          21
ac      .   .    .       .          NA
```

Can anyone help with the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.merge(df2, df1[['symbol', 's_1']], how = 'outer')
```

should return the data frame you are looking for, and you can overwrite df2 by setting it equal to that expression.